# Prove that $\inf(f+g)\ge \inf f+\inf g$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f,g:[a,b]\to \Bbb{R}$ be bounded functions. Prove that $\inf(f+g)\ge \inf f+\inf g$. Give an example where there is no equality. 
I tried to look at the image as a set, but in sets, there is equality which would contradict the other possibility. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Note that $\inf(f+g)$ means the infimum of (the range of) the function $x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)$, not the infimum of a sum of the ranges of $f$ and $g$ separately.

Comment: I did notice, but whenever I try to define it, this is where I arrive at.

Comment: For the question in the title, can you prove that $\forall x\in [a,b]\left(\inf (f)+\inf (g)\leq f(x)+g(x)=(f+g)(x)\right)$? Can you then conclude from this?

Comment: Okay, but how can I conclude that? Infimum is not necessarily in the set so I can't make sure it applies...

Comment: @Meit How can you conclude what?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** $$(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) \geq \inf f + \inf g,$$so $\inf f+ \inf g$ is a lower bound for $\{(f+g)(x) \mid x \in[a,b]\}$.

Comment: I see...So once it is a lower bound, it is only a suspect for infimum and hence the inequality holds?

Comment: Remember the definition of infimum: the greater lower bound. So yes, if you want to prove that something is less or equal to the infimum of some set, prove that this something is less or equal than all the elements in the set.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)$ be the indicator function for the rational numbers in $[a,b]$: $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$, $0$ otherwise. Then let $g(x)=1-f(x)$, the indicator function for irrational numbers. This is example where there is no equality.

Comment: An example without using "irrationality", just try two sufficiently general functions which did not have their infima at the same point. For example let $g(x)=x^2,f(x)=e^x$, then $\inf f=0$ and $\inf g=0$, now consider $x^2+e^x$, it has its infima between $(−1,1)$, which could be seen by standard arguments involving derivatives and the intermediate value theorem, but as $0 < e^{-1} \le x^2 + e^{-1} \le x^2+e^x$ on $(-1,1)$ the infima must be at least $e^{-1}$, so that we have strict inequality (by drawing a picture you will see it immediately).

Answer (score -1):

We have that $f+g(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and
\begin{align}
f(x) &\geq \text{inf}(f) \hspace{10mm} (1) \\
g(x) &\geq \text{inf}(g) \hspace{10mm} (2).
\end{align}
If we add $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $f(x)+g(x) \geq \text{inf}(f)+\text{inf}(g)$
Let $\text{inf}(f)+\text{inf}(g)=k$.
Then $k$ is an $\text{inf}$ of $f+g$ too and because the max of all $\text{inf}$'s will be $\text{inf}(f+g)$ we  have that $\text{inf}(f+g) \geq \text{inf}(f)+\text{inf}(g)$.
Note that $=$ will be when the $\text{inf}$'s of $f$ and $g$ are on the same $x_1$.

Comment: Kindly use mathjax!